# How to keep previously added data when adding new data using seed in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, ef-model-builder

First I have added data using modelBuilder in database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVziL.png)
and after this I have applied add-migration command and update-database command.
Now if I try to add new data of Id-6, then it is deleting previously added data(id-1 to 5) from the database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvEb1.png)
My question is I want to keep data from Id 1 to 5 in the database and when I again apply migration I want data with Id 1 to 6.

Now if I try to add new data of Id-6, then it is deleting previously added data(id-1 to 5) from the database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvEb1.png)
My question is I want to keep data from Id 1 to 5 in the database and when I again apply migration I want data with Id 1 to 6.

Comment: Dont remove the previously added entitys from your code. EF knows (checks by id) that they exist. Add a new `modelBuilder.Entity<Departmend>.HasData(new Department { Id = 6 ...}`. then add a new migration.
Also, please provide code as text, not images. Easier to copy, try locally, paste back to an answer. You'll get mor help, if it's easier for the helpers.

Comment: Building a Model is part of Migration when you create the mapping between the c# classes and the tables/fields in the database.  Migration is only need when the new properties are added to the database, not the values.  You should rarely do a migration.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the correct way of doing this. Instead of seeding data in DbContext itself, create separate code-first migrations to seed data.

step 01: (Create an empty migration)
add-migrations SeedData_Departments_First_Batch

step 02:
Use the up() down() methods to insert data and delete them on the rollback.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.InsertData("TableName",
        new string[] { "Id", "Name", "Age" },
        new object[,]
        {
             { Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "John", 20 },
             { Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Alex", 12 }
        }
    
protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DeleteData("TableName", "Name", new string[] { "John", "Alex" });
}
```